# UFT 11.51 - Screenshots sometimes black

Tags: qtp, webpage-screenshot, hp-uft

I have this issue that SOMETIMES my screenshots are a big black image of the correct resolution of what´s going on during the automation.

This is pretty random though, as in other executions UFT 11.51 might grab the screen correctly.

Any ideas why this might happen?

Does this ring a bell?

Comment: No. No. Does is happen with one app only? Or one specific script? What is the variable that contributes to the symptom? Find out by simplifying your scenario until the symptom disappears. Additionally, file a service request with HP.

Comment: Hi BlastOne, well actually i am testing a web application so yes it happens with one app only. The scripts are not specific. Having various modules and currently testing their funcionality. The symptom is random so simplifying my code is something that i have not done...

Comment: >>i am testing a web application so yes it happens with one app only.<< So you have no idea if it happens with a different app, too, right?

Comment: that´s right blastone, i´m afraid so.

Comment: Try iterating the same clicks on a single webpage (no page navigation). If that does not reproduce, try with a page-navigating script. Try to find what triggers the behavior. If you can ALWAYS reproduce (even only sporadically), prepare a self-contained example and confront HP with that.

Comment: You should also be 100% sure you are using up-to-date drivers (especially video drivers), and OS fixes. You could also try to reproduce on other machines. I have never seen black screenshots, and I have seen lots of them...could be a regression bug in UFT.

Comment: thanks for all your help BlastOne. I will try this when I have some time... for the moment back to work ;)

Comment: Are you running QTP with the AUT on a remote desktop dession?

Comment: sometimes and sometimes not. it might happen in any case (i see where you going with this thought ;)). Thanks!

Comment: Is the screen saver kicking in, or the desktop getting locked? Or are you working on the computer at the same time and minimizing the browser or anything? I'm assuming you are using the built-in QTP methods for taking screenshots.

Comment: Hi Xiaofu. I am actually using the oReporter library for taking snaps. Pretty sure I do not have a screensaver on and the computer is not locked - i'm there all the time.

Comment: I might have to rethink the remote desktop case though ;)

Comment: Yes, with RDP if you minimize it or disconnect the session and leaving it running remotely you will definitely get black screenshots as there is no GUI being drawn. When you say "oReporter library", this is a 3rd-party library?

Comment: For reporting, therefore screen grabbing, i use a library from the http://www.advancedqtp.com/ website. It is called Reporter Manager.

Comment: @Pixie I suggest you edit your question to make that clear, you might get more pertinent responses then, as most UFT users probably won't be familiar with it :) The usual black screen suspects probably apply regardless of the method though

Comment: i agree @xiaofu. i do not think it is because of my use of this library. thanks for clarifying.

Comment: If RDP is part of the pack, you might want to check http://bharath-marrivada.blogspot.de/2011/11/blackscreenshots-qtp-selenium-windows.html, though the content is not really top-of-the-notch ;|

Comment: Thanks BlastOne for still following this up. I am currently trying with http://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/ a program that does not let your pc sleep ;)

Answer (score 0):

Run following command from command line on target machine (where you get screenshots are a big black image)

**tscon 0 /dest:console**

N.B. run **query session** on command prompt  to check session details information.

Enjoy exploring!